# What would be the best way to show a long changelog?

Tags: lists, information, long, document, changelog

My software has frequent updates. The changelog ontains adequate amount of information about each change (often complete sentences). It's currently **more than 100,000 characters** long (16,000 words over 1,000 lines) and counting. While it's a lot of data, I like to display it so customers *get the message* there is a long evolution behind the product.

Currently each update is separated into a few unordered lists (new features, improved, bugfixes, updated libraries).

I'd like something that is **fun** and also **helps navigation** in the page, such as a timeline slider (Wayback Machine), vertical timeline (Facebook), table of contents (Wikipedia)... Currently it's just a wall of text. While I know not many people read it, I'd still like to make it as pleasing as possible.

Comment: Is this mobile only, desktop or both?

Comment: Primarily for desktop. The software is a WordPress plugin. So it's not an app. I'm fine with a clickable TOC on mobiles and a button to scroll back to top. Or an openable side panel TOC. I'm now looking into Bootstrap scrollspy with affix.

Answer (score 2):

It helps that you stated your design intent clearly: it's about communicating volume/diversity of the changelog rather than the details.

Some modern approaches to spicing up long, sectionalized content (use desktop browser to view the examples):

- [Sticky section headers](http://codepen.io/chrissp26/pen/gBrdo)
- [Parallax and scroll-updating navbars](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) (scroll down to see effect)
- [Timeline layout](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/VerticalTimeline/) (substitute version numbers or whatever for time)
- [Scrolling transitions](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/OnScrollEffectLayout/)